# How to size overcurrent protection for low voltage DC electronics?

Tags: dc, circuit-protection

I am designing a DC buck power supply for some 5V and 12V electronics, and I was wondering about generally accepted good practices when it comes to sizing overcurrent protection. Searching around, I found a lot of information for larger and higher voltage systems, but very little for very low voltage (<50V) electronics. Take this example block diagram:
[image: A Buck regulator feeds three devices: a fan, a heater, and a computer. There is an eFuse between the regulator and each device.]

A Buck regulator LMR14050QDPRRQ1 feeds three devices: a fan, a heater, and a computer. Each device is protected by an eFuse TPS259472LRPWR. The regulator can supply a max of 5 amps, and each eFuse is configured to clamp the current to each device at 1A, 1A, and 3A, respectively.

Suppose the eFuse current limits for the fan and heater are the real-world measured or spec sheet max current draws for those devices. The limit for the computer is equal to its thermal design power divided by the supply voltage. The regulator's current limit is not configurable. Both the eFuses and regulator will clamp current to the max value in the case of overdraw.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a good rule of thumb for setting current limits for simple resistive loads like the fan and heater? Spec sheet/measured max +20%?
2. What about more complex devices like the computer? Presumably, the computer has spiky current draws when it is working, so just its TDP is probably not a good measure for setting limits, and I'm not sure if trying to measure max current spikes would be either, because we can't predict all of its operating modes.
3. Is it possible to design in priority for more critical devices? In this example, increasing the current limits on the eFuses could theoretically overdraw the regulator. Suppose we want to give priority to the computer because it could fail if not supplied sufficient power. Would this affect how we set the current limits on the other devices (e.g., spec sheet +5% instead of +20%)?

Comment: Is there an extenuating reason for the extra protection? 12V 5A sounds low enough it might not matter. See for example: https://www.cui.com/blog/overview-of-limited-power-source-lps-requirements

Comment: Also mind that fans aren't very resistive/linear, indeed they may draw quite large inrush current to get moving, and can draw large ripple currents in normal operation. Heaters likewise may have lower resistance when cold; incandescent lamps are probably the most dramatic example of this, having a hot/cold ratio more than 10. So, depends on the heater material and its temp range in use.  And most active DC loads (like the computer) will have lots of filter capacitors in them, which need inrush current to start up.

Comment: That block diagram looks like TI sales material. The best advice I can give you about fuses is that you have to start with some idea of what you are trying to accomplish. What is the scenario where you would want the fuse to operate. Once you can answer that question, you will be in a much better position to size the fuse. In general, when designing a product, you have test scenarios, and the fuse is placed in the design because otherwise the outcome of the test scenario would be adverse (fire or smoke or heat, for example).

Comment: What are the fuses trying to ensure or do or protect? This question may sound simplistic but it isn't.

Comment: @TimWilliams A good point about inrush currents that really just adds to the "how do I spec overcurrent limits for complex electronics" question that I searched in vain for an answer to. I've got the heater covered; I tested the max draw after putting it in a freezer to simulate our minimum operable temperature. Regarding LPS, we want protection to prevent one shorted/damaged device from taking out other devices, rather than for human safety/fire hazard reasons.

Comment: @mkeith In my particular case, the purpose of the OCP is to prevent one damaged/shorted device from affecting the operation of another device. I chose eFuses because I want to be able to switch on/off the devices and also need current/voltage monitoring for some of them, and they seemed to offer all of these features. The safety-critical devices already have their own dedicated supplies, but the PCB is space and cost constrained, so I thought I could have some devices share regulators as long as there was short protection.

Comment: @Andyaka See comment above; the purpose of the protection is to contain failures so that damage to one device can't disable other devices. I tried to keep the question general-ish, but I guess I shouldn't have because the answer is always "it depends."

Comment: At this moment I see no reason to have fuses at all. I would use 3 current limiting buck regulators but, that's just me.

Comment: @Andyaka Agreed, however the actual system has 12 separate devices and limited space for the PCB, so having separate regulators for each device didn't fit on the board. Having non-safety-critical devices share regulators was smaller and cheaper. This did mean that I needed a MOSFET switch for each device, but I found the eFuses which do the switching and also have short protection for "free," but it does mean I need to set some kind of current limit. Still trying to find how to spec OCP for the computer - maybe the answer is "don't?"

Comment: Sometimes adding extra stuff to your board makes it less reliable, even though the intention was opposite. To an end consumer, a malfunction caused by premature tripping of an e-fuse is indistinguishable from a component failure. But you can definitely make the case that preventing the whole rail from crashing is desirable. So I think what you are doing is reasonable.

Comment: Fuse makers such as eaton and littelfuse and so-on put out app notes for sizing fuses in these types of applications. But the fuses they sell don't behave the same way as efuses so the app notes may be of limited value. https://m.littelfuse.com/technical-resources/~/media/files/littelfuse/technical%20resources/documents/reference%20documents/elec_fuse_temp_derating.pdf

Comment: If the fan stops working, do you still want the heater to run? If not, you could consider putting them both on the same efuse. (I am envisioning that the fan is blowing on a heating element, kind of like a mini space heater... and if the fan stops running, you need to turn off the heater anyway to avoid something getting too hot).

Comment: @mkeith Or conversely, if it's fanning the computer, or power supply, or etc. Nice detail.

Comment: The eFuses trip within 200 ns on over-current. If for whatever reason there is just one short peak of few usec it could reset the computer. Using eFuse for heater is simple, for fan too if startup current is considered. For the computer: why not rely on the OCP of the buck converter? Give it enough capacitors to not let CPU current peaks trip the OCP.

Comment: @datenheim Yeah, this is the direction I am leaning. I was thinking of disabling the eFuse OCP for the computer and rearranging the other devices so that only low-priority devices use the same regulator. And thanks for pointing out the 200 ns trip speed - that would definitely be a liability without sufficient capacitance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a rule of thumb. If this is for production of a consumer product, here is one approach.

You can calculate what you think the worst case current consumption is, and then build out 5 or 10 units and do 4 corner testing (or maybe more corners).

Four corner testing means in this case means high and low voltage permuted with high and low temperature. So that is hot and high, hot and low, cold and high, and finally, cold and low.

For this test, you will need a worst case firmware on the processor. The processor current draw will vary depending on what the processor is doing. You need a firmware specifically designed to create the worst case conditions for current draw on your processor. You may not know what those conditions are until you experiment a bit and try different things that your product will have to do in real life (while measuring the current).

The test must somehow detect with certainty if the efuse trips. You will have to leave the test running for a long time. Let's say at least 24 hours.

Here is a second approach. For each e-fuse, lower the limit until it trips readily in normal operation. Then double it. Cross your fingers that it will be OK.

You can also combine the two approaches by running your 4 corner testing after doubling the limits.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out. My plan right now is to disable the eFuse OCP (or just use a MOSFET switch instead) for the sensitive devices like the computer, and arrange the devices so that there are no important devices sharing a regulator with them. For the rest, corner testing will be straightforward and sufficient to spec the current limits.